# Replace imageUrl field in json with base64 encoding of the related image

Tags: json, bash, base64, weaviate

I need to import a large set of data into my weaviate DB, for it to work I need my images base64 string encoded.

I've got the following .json file with a list of objects exported from SQL:

```
[
    {
       "class": "Item",
       "image": "./public_html/images/thumbs/345.jpg",
       "itemId": "345",
       "tags": "["Funny", "Animals"]"
    }, 
    {
       "class": "Item",
       "image": "./public_html/images/thumbs/346.jpg",
       "itemId": "346",
       "tags": "["Family", "Christmas"]"
    }, 
   ...
]
```

And now I want to replace each occurence of "./public_html/images/thumbs/*.jpg" with their base64 encoded string, for this I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

json_file="input.json"
json_content=$(cat "$json_file")
new_content=""

# Iterate through the JSON array and replace "image" field values
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Extract the "image" field value
    fieldAndValue=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE '"image": "[^"]+"')

    if [ -n "$fieldAndValue" ]; then
        # Extract the path from "image"
        path=$(echo "$fieldAndValue" | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"')
    
        # Get the file content and encode it to base64
        file_content=$(cat "$path")
        base64_content=$(base64 -w 0 <<< "$file_content")   
    
        # Replace the "image" field value with the base64 content
        new_line=$(echo "$line" | awk -v target="$path" -v replacement="$base64_content" '{ gsub(target, replacement) }1') 
   else
        new_line=$line
    fi

    new_content+="$new_line"
done <<< "$json_content"

echo "${new_content}" > output.json
echo "All 'image' field values replaced with base64-encoded content."
```

The script has two problems tho:

1. It write the same base64 string in every image field.
2. Sometimes the script throws the error `/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long` for line `new_line=$(echo "$line" | awk -v target="$path" -v replacement="$base64_content" '{ gsub(target, replacement) }1')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you simply write `base64_content=$(base64 -w 0 <$path)`, instead of fiddling with `file_content`?

Comment: If you can use the [tag:jq] tool, the following filter will convert every `image` into Base64: `.[].image |= @base64`

Comment: This is not JSON: `"tags": "["Funny", "Animals"]"`.     Is the above a verbatim sample of the real data?  It looks like it wants to be `"tags" : [ "Funny", "Animals" ]` (note absence of quotes around the array).

Answer (score 0):

USING AWK

```
awk '
   BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} 
   /"image":/{ 
    "base64 -w 0 " $4 | getline x; $4=x 
  }1
' input.json > output.json
```

---

```
cat output.json
[
    {
       "class": "Item",
       "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgFeAAD/4Yk7RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAA...",
       "itemId": "345",
       "tags": ["Funny", "Animals"]
    }, 
    {
       "class": "Item",
       "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBXgFeAA .... kKNPBV0+c//2Q==",
       "itemId": "346",
       "tags": ["Family", "Christmas"]
    }
]
```